# Function for an object property returns NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

I am having trouble understanding the JS-logic in the following example. I created an object "x" with a property "bills", which is an array. Within the same object I added a method "tipCalc" which creates two further properties for x. The first property is an array "tips". In "tips" each element of "bills" is multiplied by 0.2, 0.15 or 0.1; The second property is an array "costs". In "costs", each element of "bills" is added to each element of "tips". 
When I then print the object to the console, both arrays "tips" and "costs" have elements. However, when I try to calculate the average of the elements in the array "tips" in a function averageCalc and pass "x.tips" as an argument, the function returns NaN. Can anyone explain to me, why the function that is supposed to return the average returns NaN instead? Thanks in advance!

```
var x = {
    bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    tipCalc: function() {
        this.tips = [];
        this.costs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
            if (this.bills[i] < 50) {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.2;
            } else if (this.bills[i] > 50 && this.bills[i] < 200) {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.15;
            } else {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.1;
            }
            this.costs[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i]
        }
    }
}


x.tipCalc();

function averageCalc(arr) {
    var sum = "";
    var average = "";
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
        average = sum / arr.length;
    }
    return average
}


var j = averageCalc(x.tips);
console.log(j);
```

Comment: Your calculator function is trying to compute a numeric value, but it initializes the sum and average to string values instead of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to me to be all in the `averageCalc` function. You initialise both `sum` and `average` as an empty string. This means that the subsequent additions are between a number and a string - and in such cases JS always coerces the number to a string. For one thing, this means the sum will be wrong (as it will be made by concatenating the numbers, as strings). But what is more, when you divide this string by another string, JS doesn't know how to handle that, but knows it has no way to handle dividing a string by a number, so it returns `NaN`. And this is why you get the result you do.

So, initialise `sum` and `average` with `0`, and you should be fine. (Although there is no need to initialise `average` at all, you don't need to work this out until you've added up the array.)

Comment: Actually, I've done a bit more research and it seems that the division operator, if you divide a "numeric string" by a number (as is happening here), will inded coerce the string to a number. But the problem is that `x.tips` will hold a bunch of numbers with decimal points, and since `sum` concatenates them all as strings, the result of `sum` will be a string consisting of numbers and `.` characters, which JS won't be able to convert into a number - other than as the catch-all `NaN` (indicative of an error where a numeric result was expected).

Comment: "This means that the subsequent additions are between a number and a string - and in such cases JS always coerces the string to a number. "  I am not sure if I understand this correctly: if the string " " is implicitly coerced to a number, than the problem you've described should not exist, because the function will only use numbers?

Comment: @VladKhol - oops, I see I mistyped there in an important way, surprised no-one else picked up on that! What I meant to say was that the *number* is coerced to a *string*. I'll edit the answer. Hopefully that answers the question?

Comment: Yes, now it makes sense.